# How to embed a read only view excel worksheet into a asp.net site running on an intranet

Tags: asp.net, activex, ms-wopi, office-web-app

I have a requirement where Users have to view uploaded excel files on a site running on an intranet, NB the files themselves must be hosted locally.
Solutions I have looked at include.

1. Using google docs viewer (problem requires a public URL which is not acceptable in my case).
2. office web apps thought of creating a WOPI host and WOPI client but seems it's not possible to have the client running locally.
3. explored officeviewer by edrawmax which interacts office package(issue with this runs only on IE and is too expensive).
4. Converting the excel to PDF [Failed to find a proper tool to export to PDF incase the columns are too many].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option **2** can be achieved because you can host WOPI client on-premise.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeonlineserver/deploy-office-online-server